# db2 database couldn't check if username already exists

Tags: php, web, db2, database-connection, registration

I am creating a simple registration page using IBM Db2 and PHP and all my data is saved in the Db2 database. However, I can't keep the constraint of already existing username. It is registering the user even if the username is already there in Db2. Also, it is logging in with any password entered!

I couldn't understand when the entries are shown in the database it means the data has found the right connection to the database. Then why it is not catching the constraints logic.

I just changed the MySQL functions in Db2 for PHP and there are some functions which are giving me error vibes like `db2_exec()` and `db2_fetch_assoc`.

[image]

Comment: Paste the code into the question, not as image. And provide information about the table where you store it and a typical value

Comment: register user when no error should be in else part of the code. Also, check if($user) condition is true or not...

Comment: instead of if($user) try 

iif(!empty($users) )

Comment: @data_henrik sure, thanks

Comment: @JiaaMemon what is new problem?

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Thank you so much, I missed the code should be in else part!, this solved the main part of my query

Comment: @JiaaMemon ok I have flagged it as off-topic because it was a small logical error. and will not help future readers on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user_check_query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username'"
$result = db2_exec($db,$user_check_query);
$user = db2_fetch_assoc($result);

if(!empty($user)){ // Not empty mean database already exist this username
array_push($errors,"Username exists");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this approach solved my issue in register form.
I will be really grateful if you can help me with the login problem too! I will share the code of login , as it is logging in any user with any password!

Comment: Welcome, did you fix your login problem?

Answer (score 0):

the above raised query is solved in the following code snippet;

```
if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$email = ($_POST['email']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);
$confirm_password = ($_POST['confirm_password']);

//form validation

if(empty($username)) {array_push($errors, "Username is required");}
if(empty($email)) {array_push($errors, "Email is required");}
if(empty($password)) {array_push($errors, "Password is required");}
if($password != $confirm_password) {array_push($errors, "Passwords do not match");}
if(strlen($password)<6){array_push($errors, "Password must be at least 6 characters long");}
if (!preg_match($password_requirements, $password) ) {array_push($errors,"Password must contain at least one upper case , one lower case and one digit" );}

//check db for existing user with same username

$check_username = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE username = '$username'";
$check_email = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE email = '$email'";

$res_username = db2_exec($db, $check_username);
$user_username = db2_fetch_assoc($res_username);
$res_email = db2_exec($db, $check_email);
$user_email = db2_fetch_assoc($res_email);


if(!empty($user_username)){
    array_push($errors, "Username already exists!");
}
if(!empty($user_email)){
    array_push($errors, "Email already exists!");
}
//register user if no error
elseif (count($errors) == 0) {

    //$password = md5($password);
    $query = "INSERT INTO people (username, email, password)
                VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";

    db2_exec($db,$query) or die("couldn't execute query..".db2_stmt_errormsg());

    $_SESSION['username']= $username;
    $_SESSION['success']= "You are now logged in"; 
    //echo "you are now logged in";
    header('Refresh: 0; URL=index.php', true, 301);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just add another query to check username and password

```
$check_username_password= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username' AND 
                           password = '$password'";

$result = db2_exec($db,$check_username_password);
$user = db2_fetch_assoc($result);

if(!empty($user)){ // username match with the password
 // Set your session here
 // Redirect to the page you want

  }
 else{
   // Show your error here
  }
```